# How can i make browser tab refresh other than my current tab using java script or anything?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, browser

i am making HRMS website in that i want to ask mood on specific time and its works perfectly but whenever more than one tab opened it's asking on all tab but whenever user select any mood than mood modal should be closed on all sites but now its closing only in my current tab so if i can refresh all other tab it's great for me, is it possoble to do that?

i have tried various things like used socket for close modal and currenty i have donelike refresh all sites that has same domain but it's making user experience annoying

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.